# How to include external library without using namespace

Tags: symfony-2.1

I'm not get used to SwiftMailer so I've just downloaded PHPMailer for using. The problem is PHPMailer doesn't have any "namespace" statement, so I can't use it in Controller. How to include and declare it?

Comment: You can use the global namespace: `$mail = new \PHPMailer();`

Comment: where should I put "phpmailer" folder?  "Class 'PHPMailer' not found" when I use the above statement.

Comment: If you are using Symfony 2.1, then just add the composer package from packagist to composer.json and it will handle all the autoloading and installing for you. No need to download it separately. https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: If you are using Symfony 2.1, then edit the `composer.json` file located in your root directory. In the `"require"` section, add: `"phpmailer/phpmailer": "dev-master"` and run `php composer.phar update` to install it and update other vendors. More on that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#updating-vendors

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to put it in `vendor` folder and to put the `namespace` into every files of PHPMailer. Then `use` it in Controller. It works.

Comment: No. The solution is to load PHPMailer using composer, and load it with a simple use \PHPMailer; in your class.